# Programmatic Router Navigation to Component with named router-outlet

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular4-router

I have a nebulous problem concerning a *programmatically* router navigate within an component. I really searched a lot for helpful solutions but I didn't get it, unfortunately. To confess...I'm not an angular expert because I'm still learning.
In short. I have an AppRoutingModule:

```
....
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'search',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'search',
    component: SearchComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'allgarchiv',
        component: AllgarchivComponent,
        outlet: 'search'
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

In summary I have two router-outlets, the primary one and one it's called "search" (s. above).

During loading the SearchComponent (that works!) I want to route to path "allgarchiv" (s. above; router-outlet = "search") automatically.

```
import { AfterContentInit, AfterViewInit, Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'axa-search',
  template: `
    <br>
    <ngb-tabset>
        <ngb-tab title="Suche" id="tab-search">
          <ng-template ngbTabContent>
        <!--    <a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { search: ['allgarchiv'] } }]">Test_LoadRouter</a>       -->
            <router-outlet name="search"></router-outlet> 
          </ng-template>
        </ngb-tab>
        <ngb-tab id="tab-list" [disabled]="false" title="Treffer">
          <ng-template ngbTabContent>TO FILL!!!</p>
          </ng-template>
        </ngb-tab>
    </ngb-tabset>
   `,
  styles: []
})
export class SearchComponent implements AfterContentInit {

  constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngAfterContentInit() {
//    this.router.navigate( ['allgarchiv', { outlets: { search: { relativeTo: this.route }}}] );    
    this.router.navigate( [{ outlets: { search: ['allgarchiv']}}]  );    
  }
}
```

But this doesn't work. I get following error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes.
>   URL Segment: 'allgarchiv' Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment:
>   'allgarchiv'

If you have a look within the Template I also tried this by first click on a Router-Link (Test_LoadRouter; currently comment). And this works like a charm!!
 
My question is how I could navigate to the router programmatically from SearchComponent? 
I also tried different lifecyle-hooks but without any results and the same error.
Any help is really appreciate. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, what i understood is you wanted to route to a specific child component - onload. Please try the code below:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
      path: '',
      redirectTo: 'search',
      pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
      path: 'search',
      component: SearchComponent,
      children: [
       {                                /* page loads on url '/search' with 'AllgarchivComponent' */
          path: '',
          component: AllgarchivComponent,
          outlet: 'search'
       },
       {                                /* page loads on url '/search/allgarchiv' */
         path: 'allgarchiv',
         component: AllgarchivComponent,
         outlet: 'search'
       }
]
```

}
    ];

If you only needs to load the `AllgarchivComponent`, you dont need to specify `'allgarchiv'` in your `path`. If you want to load the page with url `'search/allgarchiv'` then only you need to specify `'allgarchiv'` in the `path`. Hope this helps.

NB: using the above code, you DON'T have to give any router navigation (as you did in `ngAfterContentInit()`) in the `search component` to initially load the `AllgarchivComponent`.